# Specify a Port Number in Emacs sql-mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, emacs

I've been using Emacs's sql interactive mode to talk to the MySQL db server and gotten to enjoy it. A developer has set up another db on a new non-default port number but I don't know how to access it using sql-mysql.

How do I specify a port number when I'm trying to connect to a database?

It would be even better if Emacs can prompt me for a port number and just use the default if I don't specify. Any chances of that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After digging through the sql.el file, I found a variable that allows me to specify a port when I try to create a connection.

This option was added GNU Emacs 24.1.

> **sql-mysql-login-params**
>
> List of login parameters needed to connect to MySQL.

I added this to my Emacs init file:

```
(setq sql-mysql-login-params (append sql-mysql-login-params '(port)))
```

The default port is 0. If you'd like to set that to the default MySQL port you can customize `sql-port`

```
(setq sql-port 3306) ;; default MySQL port
```

There is a `sql-*-login-params` variable for all the popular RDMS systems in GNU Emacs 24.1. `sql-port` is used for both MySQL and PostreSQL

Comment: Thanks! Some notes: to specify default port you can use construct like  `(add-to-list 'sql-postgres-login-params '(port :default 5432))` (note the `:default` tag). And you should add `(require 'sql)` before `add-to-list`, else you get error "Symbol's value as variable is void: sql-mysql-login-params"

Comment: @seriyPS thanks!  note that you can also wrap it in a `(with-eval-after-load "sql"`… which will then only execute the code when the `sql` package is actually loaded

Answer (score 8):

```
(setq sql-mysql-options (list "-P <port number>"))
```

Answer (score 6):

I found the option using:

```
M-x customize-group
SQL
```

That included a setting labeled:

```
Mysql Options:
```

If you set the option and save it, there will be a new line added to your .emacs:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(sql-mysql-options (quote ("-P ???"))))
```

(Obviously, you ought to use the actual port number.)

I use XEmacs, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the port number with `M-x customize-variable` which will lead to a searchable list of variables. Search for `sql-mysql-options`, `sql-postgres-options`, etc. You will enter an editable UI where you can add any flag you